# Are the operations on a sparse matrix performed on a CPU? (TensorFlow)

Tags: tensorflow

When I read a timeline object describing the running time of a network which uses sparse matrices and operations such as `embeding_lookup_sparse`, the trace only mentions CPU. Are there no operations performed on GPU? I think there should be as the running time is about 100 ms while the trace only shows 5 ms.

[image]